# what is best practice for Angular drop down menu & ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, ng-options

good day, i created a drop dow menu on AngularJS. but it return to me an object not an item {"deptName":"IT","id":"1"}. i need to return the id only to my table. 
is there any thing i need to change on ng-options="item.deptName  for item in department.departments"
see the sample:

**JS**

```
angular.module('firstApp', [])

.controller('EmpController', function() {
    var vm = this;
    // define a list of items
    vm.employees = [{
        name: 'Alex',
        id: '2233',
        dept: 'IT'
    }, {
        name: 'Scott',
        id: '2244',
        dept: 'IT'
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        id: '2255',
        dept: 'IT'
    }];
})

.controller('DeptController', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.departments = [{
        deptName: 'IT',
        id: '1'
    }, {
        deptName: 'Finance',
        id: '2'
    }, {
        deptName: 'Marketing',
        id: '3'
    }];
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="jumbotron">


    <h1>The Selected is </h1>
    <h2>{{main.employeeData.dept}}</h2>

    <!-- form to add computer to the list -->
    <form class="form-inline" ng-controller="DeptController as department">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Dept menu</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!--<select  required="true" ng-model="main.employeeData.dept" ng-options="item.deptName  for item in department.departments">-->
                <!--<option value="">Select Category</option>-->
                <!--</select>-->

                <select required="true" ng-model="main.employeeData.dept" ng-options="item.id as item.deptName for item in department.departments">
                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `as` of `ng-options` like `item.id as item.deptName` .It will show `item.deptName` on drop-down value & assign `item.id` value to the respective select `ng-model`

**Markup**

```
 <select required="true" ng-model="main.employeeData.dept" ng-options="item.id as item.deptName for item in department.departments">
      <option value="">Select Category</option>
 </select>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/sRWyFy4dhGMpbvuOsq2y?p=preview) here

Comment: Glad to know that, Thanks ;)